# Scraping pin coordinates from an interactive map with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the dropped pin coordinates on  [this Interactive map](https://kaupunkipyorat.hsl.fi/en/helsinki/stations).
The map is made with [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) library for JavaScript. It's getting the coordinates somehow but this information cannot be found on the website itself.

**Question:** How can I assess coordinate information with Selenium if I don't even know where it is?

**To save some time:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "..."
driver = webdriver.chrome(PATH)


driver.get("https://kaupunkipyorat.hsl.fi/en/helsinki/stations")
driver.quit()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page makes a request to https://api.digitransit.fi/routing/v1/routers/hsl/bike_rental, which contains exactly the information you want.

To get the names of the first five stations, we could write:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://api.digitransit.fi/routing/v1/routers/hsl/bike_rental")
json = response.json()
for station in json["stations"][:5]:
     print(station["name"])
```

Which prints:

```
Luhtimäki
Petikontie
Martinkyläntie
Vantaanpuisto
Vehkala station
```

Comment: Oh wow, Thank you very much! May I ask how you found the request source?